# react@18 with react-router-dom@6 conflcit with babel/webpack?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, react-router-dom

I have the following version of those libraries:

```json
{
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.8.1",
    "@babel/cli": "^7.20.7",
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.12",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.2",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.2"
}
```

This is my routes that are configured inside this file:

```
export default function Routes() {
  return useRoutes([
    {
      path: "auth",
      children: [
        {
          path: "login",
          element: (
            <GuestGuard>
              <Login />
            </GuestGuard>
          ),
        },
      ],
    },
    //Dashboard Routes
    {
      path: "dashboard",
      element: (
        <AuthGuard>
          <Dashboard />
        </AuthGuard>
      ),
    },
    {
      path: "/",
      element: (
        <AuthGuard>
          <Dashboard />
        </AuthGuard>
      ),
    },
    { path: "*", element: <Navigate to="/404" replace /> },
  ]);
}
```

And I am using `Routes()` inside the Main component:

```
const Main = () => {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Router>
                <Routes />
            </Router>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```

According to my `Routes` components, I am expecting to have 3 available URLs in my project:

1. `"/auth/login"`
2. `"/dashboard"`
3. `"/"`

I can see that I am having a conflict between babel/webpack and react-router-dom.

While trying to go to one of the URLs above(not '/') I am receiving this error:

```
Cannot GET /dashboard
```

I've never encountered such an error, and this is the first time I have manually set webpack and babel to my project, so I guess the issue is coming from there.

this is my webpack.config.js:

```js
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');
const dotenv = require('dotenv')

// this will update the process.env with environment variables in .env file
dotenv.config();

module.exports = {
  entry: './index.js',
  mode: 'development',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    filename: 'index_bundle.js',
  },
  target: 'web',
  devServer: {
    port: '3000',
    static: {
      directory: path.join(__dirname, 'public')
    },
    open: true,
    hot: true,
    liveReload: true,
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.json'],
    alias: {
      process: "process/browser"
    },
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: 'babel-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      process: 'process/browser',
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html')
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': JSON.stringify(process.env)
    })
  ]
};
```

What am I missing here?