# React-Router-DOM@6.3.0 does not render child components

Tags: reactjs, react-router, babeljs, react-router-dom, webpack-dev-server

I am trying to configure a route child to an existing work route.

I have 3 main routes that work perfectly, and one of them has 1 child.

1. /
2. /dashboard
3. /auth
   3.1 /auth/login

this is my `routes` object:

```
    export const Routes = () => [
    {
        path: "/",
        element: (
            <Dashboard/>
        )
    }, {
        path: "/dashboard",
        element: (
            <Dashboard/>
        )
    }, {
        path: "auth",
        children: [
            {
                path: "login",
                element: (
                    <Login />
                ),
            },
        ],
    }
]
```

I am using this object inside my Main component on `RouterProvider` using the function `createBrowserRouter`.

This is my Main.js file:

```
import React from "react";
import {createBrowserRouter, Outlet, RouterProvider} from "react-router-dom";
import {Routes} from "../Routes";

const Main = () => {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <RouterProvider router={createBrowserRouter(Routes())}/>
            <Outlet/>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
export default Main;
```

This is my Login component:

```
...imports

const theme = createTheme();

const Login = () => {
    const [errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = useState("");
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        setErrorMsg("");
        event.preventDefault();
        const data = new FormData(event.currentTarget);
        performLogin({
            email: data.get('email'),
            password: data.get('password'),
        }).then((response) => {
            axiosInstance.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = `Bearer ${response.data.token}`;
            localStorage.setItem("token", response.data.token);
            dispatch(setToken(response.data.token));
            navigate("/dashboard");
        }).catch((error) => {
            setErrorMsg(error.error);
        });
    };

    return (
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <Container component="main" maxWidth="xs">
                <CssBaseline/>
                <Box
                    sx={{
                        marginTop: 8,
                        display: 'flex',
                        flexDirection: 'column',
                        alignItems: 'center',
                    }}
                >
                    <Avatar sx={{m: 1, bgcolor: 'secondary.main'}}>
                        <LockOutlinedIcon/>
                    </Avatar>
                    <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
                        Sign in
                    </Typography>
                    {errorMsg !== '' &&
                        <Alert severity="error" sx={{mt: 3, width: "100%"}}>{errorMsg}</Alert>
                    }
                    <Box component="form" onSubmit={handleSubmit} noValidate sx={{mt: 1}}>
                        <TextField
                            margin="normal"
                            required
                            fullWidth
                            id="email"
                            label="Email Address"
                            name="email"
                            autoComplete="email"
                            autoFocus
                        />
                        <TextField
                            margin="normal"
                            required
                            fullWidth
                            name="password"
                            label="Password"
                            type="password"
                            id="password"
                            autoComplete="current-password"
                        />
                        <Button
                            type="submit"
                            fullWidth
                            variant="contained"
                            sx={{mt: 3, mb: 2}}
                        >
                            Sign In
                        </Button>
                        <Grid container>
                            <Grid item xs>
                                <Link href="#" variant="body2">
                                    Forgot password?
                                </Link>
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid item>
                                <Link href="#" variant="body2">
                                    {"Don't have an account? Sign Up"}
                                </Link>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </Box>
                </Box>
                <Copyright sx={{mt: 8, mb: 4}}/>
            </Container>
        </ThemeProvider>
    );
}

export default Login;
```

While trying to go to the regular routes, its work as expected, but when I am trying to go to `/auth/login` I get blank screen with those error inside the console:

> login:8          GET http://localhost:3000/auth/index_bundle.js
> net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

> login:10 Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:3000/auth/index_bundle.js' because its MIME
> type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is
> enabled.

BTW, if you didn't notice, /auth is rendering the Login component the same as /auth/login, which indicates that the component is valid.

BTW2, this app is configured with babel and webpack could be a relation to that?

Those are my webpack/babel versions:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.20.7",
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.12",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.2",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.2",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "process": "^0.11.10",
    "webpack": "^5.75.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.0.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.11.1"
  }
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why is the `Login` component trying to render itself on a nested route? Can you [edit] to include the `Login` component?

Comment: At a minimum I think you've at least 2 possible issues: (1) the server isn't configured to serve the root index.html file for all page requests, and (2) the `Login` component isn't rendering an `Outlet` for nested routes to render content. Please update the post with details regarding these.

Comment: I have uploaded the Login component, can you please tell me why I need to add an Outlet for the Login component, I just want to render it not nest inside it.

Comment: Because `"/auth"` is rendering `Login` and you've configured `"auth/login"` as a nested route that also renders `Login` for some reason. If you want `"/auth/login"` to be reachable then the parent route needs to render an `Outlet` component for the nested routes. Perhaps you don't need the nested `"/auth/login"` route ***or*** you don't want to render `Login` on `"/auth"`?

Comment: Is this post related to your other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75386368/react18-with-react-router-dom6-conflcit-with-babel-webpack) from this morning?

Comment: Yes, I can pass on the `/auth` to render Login and only `/auth/login` will render it, I tried to remove the `element` prop from `/auth` and it's still the same issue.
Did I do a valid change that require?

Comment: About your second question, yes it is my question, I managed to overcome the issue but I cannot tell how I fixed it, I did a lot of things so I can't remember

Comment: Can you [edit] to reflect the current code you are using? If you are only rendering `Login` on `"/auth/login"` then I think you are in issue (1) with the server not returning the root index.html file for all page requests.

Comment: @DrewReese, I've updated the Routes function with the new change, please look :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251750/discussion-between-itzik-b-and-drew-reese).

Answer (score 0):

I have found the issue, the problem is that webpack is trying to access `index_bundle.js` inside `/auth/`, which is actually inside `/`.

option 1:

I needed to add the `publicPath` variable inside webpack settings:

```
module.exports = {
...
   output:{
   ...
      publicPath: '/',
   ...
   }
...
}
```

option 2:
Add this to index.html in your head section

```
<base href="/" />
```